# oracle imp: schema prefix used in file generated by the indexfile option

Tags: database, oracle, import

Here is my use case:

1. I have two different dump files, from two different external sources, both exported with exp (so classical dumps): `export1.dmp` and `export2.dmp` (as far as I can see, they were both exported with exp version V11.02.00. But I don't know anything more about them.)
2. For each one I run the imp utility (on Oracle 12c) with the `indexfile` option, in order to generate an sql file containing the table and index create commands, like this:

(a) `imp mytargetuser/password file=export1.dmp  full=y indexfile=create1.sql`

(b) `imp mytargetuser/password file=export2.dmp  full=y indexfile=create2.sql`

In `create1.sql` every create statement gets generated with the table/index name prefixed by `mytargetuser` (which is what I want), like:

```
create table mytargetuser.table1 ...;

create index mytargetuser.index1 ...;
```

However, in `create2.sql` every create statement gets generated with the table/index name prefixed by `someuser` (which is probably a user in the original database, from where the dump was made):

```
create table someuser.table1 ...;

create index someuser.index1 ...;
```

Any idea why this difference in the output of the indexfile option? And if there is any way I can force imp to always behave like in the first case above (a): to use the user I run imp with as the schema prefix in the generated script (or to not prefix at all the table/index names with a schema name, that would be also good for me)? (Once again, I cannot influence in any way the how the dump is generated on the other end.)

Comment: Have you tried [`fromuser` and `touser` options](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-original-import-utility.html#GUID-D3F9B4B1-F107-4499-B529-544D233811B5)?

Comment: No, because I wouldn't know what to give for the fromuser option. As I said, I have no way of knowing which user was exported in the dump. I just have the dump file, and that's all. Nice try though :)

Comment: To quote one Sorin, _"someuser (which is probably a user in the original database, from where the dump was made)"_. And it didn't cross you mind to try that?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @mustaccio, but your reasoning is wrong again (it seems you don't really get the essence of my use case and questions). I get that "someuser" in the resulting indexfile only **after I run the imp command**.

Comment: Of course, I could then parse the file and extract "someuser", and replace it everywhere with mytargetuser in the file. Or delete the file, and run again imp, now with fromuser touser. But all that is just a workaround, and not a too elegant one (although probably that's what I'm gonna have to do eventually). And it is beside the point.

Comment: The point is, why exactly the same imp command gives a different output with two different dump files? And if there is any way to make this command behave like in the first example always, from the very first run. I am looking for **to the point** answers to these questions. Anybody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour is indeed explained [in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-original-import-utility.html#GUID-01F8E58D-760A-4E8C-A300-23B6AE651639):

> If you do not specify TOUSER, then Import will do the following:
>
> - Import objects into the FROMUSER schema if the export file is a full dump or a multischema, user-mode export dump file
> - Create objects in the importer's schema (regardless of the presence of or absence of the FROMUSER schema on import) if the export
>     file is a single-schema, user-mode export dump file created by an
>     unprivileged user

Based on the above one might surmise that `export2.dmp` "is a full dump or a multischema, user-mode export dump file", while `export1.dmp` "is a single-schema, user-mode export dump file created by an unprivileged user".

Comment: I think that's the correct answer, thank you @mustaccio! I have come to pretty much the same conclusion in the meantime, while further working on a solution/workaround on the import side. And I was just going to post my findings. But you already did provide the correct answer, thank you for your assistance with this. Next time I'll make a better effort to thoroughly read through the manual.